# How to converts the createdAt date from AWS to the day of the week

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, date, format, date-conversion

I am trying to extract the day of the week from the AWS createdAt date format.

For example, given this date format: `2021-10-20T17:05:26.758Z` find the day of the week (ie. Wednesday, Monday...)

I am working in Javascript and I am using AWS Amplify and Dynamo DB.

Answer (score 1):

This date `2021-10-20T17:05:26.758Z` is a valid ISO 8601 date format,
so you can use `Date()` and `toLocaleDateString()` to get day name:

```js
const dayName = new Date('2021-10-20T17:05:26.758Z').toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });

console.log(dayName);
```

Comment: Worth noting while the timestamp is UTC, this method returns the local day so while many will get Wednesday, anyone that is UTC +7 or greater will get Thursday. Also the "-US" subtag is redundant. :-)